# Adding elements in a list one at a time

Tags: prolog

I want to create an empty list and then somehow add elements to it one at a time.

```
call(X):-
 **Here I want to add X into a list L which was initially empty.
   Everytime call(X) is called a new value of X is added to the list L**
```

How can I do this ??

Comment: The obvious question here is, what is this list for and how are you going to use it. Depending on your actual problem, different solutions might exist.

Comment: Generaly you should avoid (if possible) variable modification, such modifications breaks prolog declarativeness. Consider returning modified list as another parameter. If modification can't be avoided(we really leave in changing world) then asssert() is acceptable solution. Note: theoretically it's possible to create your own list implementation which allows adding items to the tail but such an attempt actually isn't worthy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does it mean, "add to list"? And how are you going to use this list?

One possible way is to write the list as a table of facts, one fact per list element:

```
add_front(X) :-
    asserta(list(X)).

add_back(X) :-
    assertz(list(X)).
```

To retrieve the list, you can use `findall(X, list(X), List)`:

```
?- add_front(a), add_front(b), add_back(X).
true.

?- findall(X, list(X), List).
List = [b, a, _G342].
```

This is a valid solution, but if feels wrong, if you are actually dealing with a list. Where do the values for this list come from? Even if they come from user interaction, there are better ways to make a list, for example:

```
read_list(List) :-
    read(T),
    (   T == end_of_file
    ->  true
    ;   format('~w~n', [[T|List]]),
        read_list([T|List])
    ).
```

You need to remember that your input has to be a valid prolog term and end the line with a dot:

```
?- read_list([]).
|: 1.
[1]
|: b.
[b,1]
|: foo(bar).
[foo(bar),b,1]
|: X.
[_G1279,foo(bar),b,1]
```

... and so on. It will succeed when you interrupt it with an end-of-file. You have access to the full list on every input.

If you start with a list you want to trasform, you should look into `maplist`, for example.